# How is the overall battery level calculated in Microsoft Surface Book 2?

Tags: laptop, battery, microsoft-surface

I have been reading information about the two batteries in the Microsoft Surface Book 2 laptop; however, I have not been able to find exactly how the overall battery level is calculated.

For example, if I run `WMIC Path Win32_Battery Get EstimatedChargeRemaining`, I get `100%` for the first battery, and `96%` for the second one; however, the overall battery level is displayed as `97%` when I click the battery icon in the tray, which is not the average between the two levels.

So, how is the overall battery level calculated in these laptops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Depending on which model (13 or 15")](https://surfacetip.com/how-much-surface-battery-capacity-in-mah/) the battery in the base is around 3 times the size of the one in the tablet portion and is used first.

Taking the 15" model:

```
Surface Book 2 15"  90.0 Wh     12,000 mAh, 7.5 V   17 hours
— clipboard         23.0 Wh     3,066 mAh,  7.5 V   5 hours
— base              67.0 Wh     8,933 mAh,  7.5 V   12 hours
```

So the total battery left when you are at 96% on the main battery will be

```
(0.96 * 67) + 23 = 87.32 Wh remaining.
```

Then we divide by the **total** capacity

```
87.32 / 90 = 0.97022 = 97.022%
```

Which seems to pretty much correlate to the figure you are getting.

It is not an average of all batteries as that figure is useless when you have asymmetric batteries. It is the actual capacity left.

Comment: Thank you, this was very useful. Do you know if there's a way to get these values through `CMD` without using `powercfg /batteryreport `?

Comment: @Gael not really, for my laptop I cannot get the current battery capacity as (in powershell) `(Get-WmiObject win32_battery).fullchargecapacity` returns nothing. Otherwise, again in Powershell, you can do something like `(Get-WmiObject win32_battery).EstimatedChargeRemaining * <your battery capacity in mAh ffrom BatteryReport>` The internet is not much help apart from the battery report.

Comment: What's "clipboard" in this context ? Thanks

Comment: @KaKi87 the Surface Book is a two part device which consists of a tablet PC (the "clipboard") where a CPU, screen and battery is stored that can be attached to a "base" unit which contains a keyboard, extra battery and higher powered GPU. The tablet can operate completely independently of the base unit and is referred to as the "clipboard".